# Can I set HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout() after couple of readLine()

Tags: java, comet, httpclient, chunked-encoding, http-streaming

I am trying to write a JAVA based comet HTTP streaming. I am using apache httpClient 4.x for this. Since, it is comet HTTP streaming, all the events are coming to the client in the form of chunked data. Since the connection may stay opended for long time, I am trying to implement the dynamic setting of SO_TIMEOUT after some readLine() data from the server.

When i set the value for SO_TIMEOUT after readLine from the BufferedInputStream, it is not taking effect, it is still using the original SO_TIMEOUT value set in before the execute() method call.

Following is the definition of SO_TIMEOUT from apache website:
**Defines the socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT) in milliseconds, which is the timeout for waiting for data or, put differently, a maximum period inactivity between two consecutive data packets). A timeout value of zero is interpreted as an infinite timeout.**

As per the above definition, SO_TIMEOUT value should get reset by the apache httpclient on the arrival of every chunked data. If that is the case, it should accept my newer SO_TIMEOUT value. Any idea on how I can set the SO_TIMEOUT value after reading couple of lines form BufferedInputStream?

Answer (score 2):

> As per the above definition, SO_TIMEOUT value should get reset by the apache httpclient on the arrival of every chunked data.

I think you are reading meaning into the quoted javadoc that was not intended by the authors.  I don't read the text to mean that you can dynamically adjust the timeout while reading the response stream.

In fact, if you examine the code of `setSoTimeout()` and follow through to the places where the parameter is used, it is clear that value is only used when a HTTP method is about be made.  Changes made after that time have no effect on the way that the current request or response is handled.  Look for `HttpMethodDirector.applyConnectionParams`.

> Any idea on how I can set the SO_TIMEOUT value after reading couple of lines form BufferedInputStream?

I think your best bet would be to extend the HttpConnection class to add a method that changes the SO_Timeout for the connection's socket.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that after you call `open()` on the HttpConnection object, any changes to the HttpConnectionParams won't take affect.  Take a look at the [Javadocs](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/HttpConnection.html) for HttpConnection.  It says:

The following options are set on the socket **before** getting the input/output streams in the open() method:

...
Socket.setSoTimeout(int)    SO_TIMEOUT  HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(int)
...

Answer (score 0):

[HttpConnection.setSocketTimeout](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/HttpConnection.html#setSocketTimeout%28int%29). 'Sets the SO_TIMEOUT value directly on the underlying socket.' That will take effect with the next blocking read on the underlying socket. Of course if you have a BufferedInputStream around that and it already has data in it you won't be blocking at all until you exhaust that.